# Spring @cacheable in web-service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, caching

**Hello everyone!**
I am setting up caching in my web app via Spring @Cacheable.
The problem is that i have set all environment and caching doesn't work at all.
As i see the first call of `checkCache()` method must write some logs unlike the next ones that should be called from cache.

Here is my code:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.java.MyService", serviceName = "MyService", name = "MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);

  @Override
  @Cacheable("dict")
  public String checkCache() {
      logger.info("Cache doesn't work((");
      return "checkCache";
  }
}
```

Spring-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.java"/>
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" name="dict"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `@WebService` isn't a spring managed bean... Caching will only work for spring managed beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum Man, that works for me, thanks a lot!